# In a project using vue-router, children are displayed correctly in route-view in the local environment, but not in the production environment

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using vue-router to create projects.
http://localhost:8080/#/staff is the parent component and . /staff/staff1 and . /staff/staff2.. I want to display child components like this.

When I run npm run serve in the vscode terminal and check the operation in the local environment, staff1 and staff2 are displayed correctly, but when I upload the file to github and check in the browser, the child components are not displayed.
Since they are displayed in the local environment, I think the notation in router.js and  tags is correct, but I cannot find a solution.

I am Japanese and using a translation tool, so I apologize for my poor English, but I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

router.js is as follows

```
// ...
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: About
  },
  // ...
  {
    path: '/staff',
    name: 'staff',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */'../pages/Staff.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
      },
      {
        path: 'hanji',
        name: 'hanji',
        component: import('../components/talents/hanji.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'meguru',
        name: 'meguru',
        component: import('../components/talents/meguru.vue')
      },
  // ...
```

The staff.vue is as follows

```
<template>
  <div class="wrap">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        class="center my-3"
      >
        <h2>ママたちのご紹介</h2>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <div id="container">
      ...
      <router-view />
    </div>
    <v-row class="mt-4">
      <v-col
        v-for="staff in staffs"
        :key="staff"
      >
        <router-link
          :to="'/staff/' + staff.name"
          class="link"
        >
          <img
            :src="staff.src"
            width="427"
            height="640"
            class="img"
          >
        </router-link>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

data is defined as follows

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      staffs: {
        0: {
          name: 'hanji',
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          src: require('@/img/talent/hanji.jpg')
        },
        1: {
          name: 'meguru',
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          src: require('@/img/talent/santa.jpg')
        },
　　　　　...
    }
  },
```

Photos of local and production environments.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWQh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HIfO.png)

If anyone has had a similar situation, I would like to know the solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement. Please provide a way to reproduce, you only have urls on screenshots. What is the exact route you have a problem with? There's no "staff/staff1" route in the code you posted. Btw there are missing route warnings in *development* screenshot.